# Is it possible to detect a simple negative-weight cycle of weight $N$ in polynomial time?

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

Given a directed graph and an integer $N$, is it possible to detect a simple negative-weight cycle whose edges sum to $N$ in polynomial time? I thought about modifying the Floyd-Warshall algorithm to check if the diagonals equal $N$ as they get set, but I realized this wouldn't work if a vertex appeared in multiple negative-weight cycles.

Comment: It is possible to modify Floyd-Warshall so that, even with an input graph containing negative weight cycles, all of the off diagonal entries will not contain any cycles, and the diagonal entries $i\to i$ will not contain any smaller cycles besides one traversal of the large cycle $i\to i$. But Floyd-Warshall will only find the smallest (or largest) cycle $i\to i$ for each vertex $i$. Thus you could deduce in polynomial time, for each $i$, whether the number $N$ is between the two numbers `weight(smallest cycle i->i)` and `weight(largest cycle i->i)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't (not unless P=NP).  Take an unweighted directed graph on $n$ vertices, and set all of the edge weights to $-1$.  Now there is a simple cycle of weight $-n$ if and only if there is a Hamiltonian circuit in the original graph.  But detecting the existence of Hamiltonian circuits is NP-hard.  Therefore your problem is NP-hard, too.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to graph theory and don't quite get it. A Hamiltonian circuit is a simple cycle that visits each vertex in the graph exactly once. But in the problem I have given, we don't require that. So, I'm just confused on how your stated problem is equivalent to mine.

Comment: (∩｀-´)⊃━☆ﾟ.*･｡ﾟ  reduction...

Comment: @Jake, when I ask for the weight of the cycle to be $-n$, where $n$ is the number of vertices, that does effectively require that each vertex be visited exactly once.

Comment: @ D.W.  - I'm blown by your logic. Just to ensure my understanding is correct, by this reasoning, finding positive cycle of weight n will also be as hard as HAM-CIRCUIT. Isn't it!

Comment: @KGhatak, If there is a flaw in the logic, I'd be interested to hear where it is.  By this logic, finding a *simple* positive cycle of weight $n$ will also be as HAM-CIRCUIT.  I believe that is correct.  Note that the "simple" part is essential.

Comment: @ D. W. - Thank you, and I noticed the importance of 'simple cycle' as well as not needing the directed graph to be a 'simple' one. In my previous comment, I meant I'm quite amazed with the simplicity of your reasoning. Hats off, and thank you again - I learnt something very good from you.

Comment: @ D. W. - Wondering if you could pls comment on this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3379088/is-composition-of-isomorphism-and-complementation-of-a-graph-commutative